# How to plot a 1D K-means cluster

Tags: matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a vector (X2) and I would like to investigate the groups they can form.
I have performed the K-means analysis, whith 2 clusters:
shape X2 = (19,1)

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2,random_state=123)                 
kmeans.fit(X2)                                                
label = kmeans.fit_predict(X2)
 
print(label)
[0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
```

Now I would like to make the scatter plot of these 2 clusters.
Could someone help me with the plot.

I'm not sure how I can associate the label with my vector (X2) and what to put in x-axis and y-axis.

I would like to have something like this:
[image: K means 2 clusters]

But I don't know how to organize the plot, because the labels are not the x-axis. I now the y-axis (X2), what is missing is the x-axis and how to associate the labels with colors to X2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot your x points as indexes and y points as the real values (X2). And if we come to the point that you want to associate the colors you can use 'c' keyword of matplotlib's scatter method.

As an example:

```
plt.scatter([i for i in range(len(X2))], X2, c=labels)
```

color(c) = labels, is going to scatter indexes that has same corresponding label with same color. You can also use c="red" to make every point red.

Comment: The first argument is identical to the simpler `range(len(X2))`.

Comment: Thank you! that is exactly what I want!

Comment: @Basil do you know how I can set the legend for each color,?

Comment: @JenifferBarreto I don't know how to do it in the case of a 1D array. I would recommend splitting `X2` into multiple arrays where each new array contains the elements of `X2` that are associated with the corresponding cluster id in `labels`. That is a nontrivial exercise -- I believe you will want to preserve the plotted "x" index of each element from the original `X2`, otherwise the plot will not look like you expect.

Comment: @JenifferBarreto, You're welcome! And I don't know for sure but searched a bit, you can give specific colors for each cluster label, so it can be ['red','red', 'blue','blue'] with that way since you know which label is which color, using legend can be easier.

Comment: @JenifferBarreto: Actually, there is a simple way: assign the scatter plot call to something, say `artist`.  Then try the following: `plt.legend(artist.legend_elements()[0], ['c_0', 'c_1'])` where the strings inside the list are your desired legend labels.  For default labels, just do `plt.legend(*artist.legend_elements())` instead. Note the `*` there.

Comment: For more customization options, see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html

Comment: Check out the examples from this resource. https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-clusters-with-pythons-matplolib-35ae03d87489

Answer (score 0):

The plot that you display is a 3-dimensional graphic, the space X (x,y) and the class.

If I understand your question, you are clustering samples which are in one dimension. You don't need a 3-dimensional graph but a 2-dimensional. You can forget the color of the graphic and use the y-axis to represent the class (-1,1).

You can project them on a 2-dimensional space if you want by adding a fake dimension (y=0) and use the color parameter of matplotlib with the class predicted.